# Springboot: Http request attributes(RequestContextHolder) in AuditorAware class

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to read header from the request in AuditorAwareImpl class with following

`HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();`

but getting null pointer? How can i read current request attributes in auditor aware?

i tried defining

```
 @Bean
public RequestContextFilter requestContextFilter() {
    RequestContextFilter requestContextFilter = new RequestContextFilter();
    requestContextFilter.setThreadContextInheritable(true);
    return requestContextFilter;
}
```

But no help

Thanks

Comment: Where do you get NPE specifically?

Comment: `((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes())` this will be null

Comment: Are you doing this inside a method or assigning to a field?

Comment: inside the method. following is the class code
`public class AuditorAwareImpl implements AuditorAware<String> {

    @Override
    public Optional<String> getCurrentAuditor(){
       HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
        return Optional.of("Admin");
    }
}`

example of full code from
http://progressivecoder.com/spring-boot-jpa-auditing-example-with-auditoraware-interface/